# how to query a custom object within a channel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getstream-io, getstream-chat

I have this custom data in the channel

```
{
 channelHashId: '111122222',
 cid: '111111',
 data: {
   custom: {
     name: "testing"
   }
 }
 address: "my address",
}
```

i tried

```
const filter = { type: 'messaging', data: { custom: { name: 'testing' }  } };
const sort = [{ last_message_at: -1 }]; 

const channels = await chatClient.queryChannels(filter, sort, {
    watch: true, // this is the default
    state: true,
});
```

but i get an error 'invalid field operation',

but if i do

```
const filter = { type: 'messaging', address: 'my address'  } };
const sort = [{ last_message_at: -1 }]; 

const channels = await chatClient.queryChannels(filter, sort, {
    watch: true, // this is the default
    state: true,
});
```

it works fine

please help

Comment: What do the docs say?

Comment: nested object isn't supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `queryMembers` (see [docs](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/react/query_members/)) instead of `queryChannels`.

Under the hood, since the data field is of a reference type (an object), `queryChannels` would compare the reference instead of the content of your object.

Comment: isn't queryMembers only look for members information in the channel? how would this search for data in the channel object?